# Affecting left edges and right edges separately in a binary tree via tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I want to use tikz-qtree to make a binary tree where left edges are red and labelled 0 while right edges are black and labelled 1.  The following is the way I am currently doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree[.a \edge[color=red] node[color=black, auto=right]{0};
             [.b \edge[color=red] node[color=black, auto=right]{0}; c \edge node[auto=left]{1}; d ]
         \edge node[auto=left]{1}; [.e \edge[draw=none]; {} \edge node[auto=left]{1}; f ] ]
\end{document}
```

and that code produces the following tree:

[image]

(This is supposed to be used for a larger tree, but the code for this is already ugly enough.)  Can someone show me a better way?  Tips to make the code more readable are also welcome.

For the sake of generality, I would also be interested in solutions that generalize to n-trees (where each node has n children), though I don't have plans to use that at the moment.

I am happy to see solutions that use other packages.

Comment: Please edit your post to make the snippet compilable and say whether you are open to solutions using other packages and what an n-tree is.

Comment: If you need to do this automatically, then `forest` is probably a better solution.

Comment: @cfr hopefully the code compiles (I’m on my phone right now so I don’t know how to check); if so, I have done both.

Comment: For an *n*-tree, what would the colouring/numbering scheme be, though?  Also, for a unary branch as in your e-f, what really determines if it's a left or right branch?

Comment: @AlanMunn Could you have a look in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81492/discussion-between-cfr-and-marmot if you've got a minute? If I pull a y coordinate from a point (thanks to marmot), then it changes when I open a loop, despite the `\xdef`. And I don't know why. (Also, chat is the only usable bit of the site at the moment.)

Comment: In your tree, though, each node doesn't have n children for any value of n. Ignoring leaves, some nodes have 2 children and others have 1. So I don't see how this could be 'generalised' to an n-tree.

Comment: @cfr they do; I’ve just made some of them invisible.  If possible, I would prefer a generalization to allow me to do something similar to allow me to keep making some edges and nodes invisible.

Comment: Then you don't want to generate the tree programmatically? In which case, I don't see what there is to the general case beyond the binary.

Comment: @cfr If you mean what I think you mean by programmatically, I think I do want it done programmatically.  In the general case, I might want, say, each edge numbered according to how many edges from the leftmost edge it is, counting invisible ones (or I might color them accordingly).

Comment: That isn't constructing the tree programmatically, but only annotating it programmatically. You can do either, but obviously there's no general solution of the kind you now seem to want. I mean, you have to tell it what to do, whether that's labelling all the left edges '0' or counting all the edges from the left or colouring them or whatever. So I still don't see what you're actually hoping to get from an answer. 'The general case' seems to mean 'whatever I want at the time', but, clearly, a solution can't provide that in the absence of an effective crystal ball.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the 'forest' tag. That will give you an idea of what can be done. Annotating your current tree is trivial in Forest. You just need something like `where n=1{edge+=red, edge label={node[midway, left] {0}}}{edge label={node[midway, right]{1}}}` in the tree's preamble.